# C# .NET VSTO Excel Add-In Global Error Handler Options

Tags: c#, .net, excel, vsto

I have an Excel Add-In created using VSTO and C# .NET. I am interested in creating a handler for unhandled exceptions. Based on some research and other posts, there are a couple of events that I can register for and they seem to do the trick.

So, something like this:

```
    private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += this.CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
    }

    private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        var errorDialog = new ErrorDialog("Something went wrong", e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
        errorDialog.ShowDialog();            
    }
```

Great. HOWEVER, as soon as the error dialog shows and exits, i.e. the code above returns/completes, the code that triggered the exception resumes exactly where it left off, thus re-triggering the exception. It becomes an infinite loop.

In WPF, we would simply mark it as handled, `(e.Handled = true;)` and that would take care of it. However I don't see a similar option here in WinForms.

What are my options with Excel Add-Ins VSTO/Win Form exception handlers?

The only thing I can think of is to catch the first event and ask the user to restart the app.

There has to be something better. How can I really handle the exception?

Comment: Look at try catch code constructs

Comment: Thanks. It's hard to locate every possible point of failure. I would rather be safe than sorry and not have the app crash unexpectedly.

Comment: There seem to be various attempts at such solution: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=vsto+appdomain+unhandled+exceptions&t=iphone&ia=web